# How to make acts_as_list make the added item have the top position?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-list

I have a group of items which uses the acts_as_list gem. As of now, when a new item is added, acts_as_list will give the item the lowest position, making it show up as the last item on the list. Is there a way to make it so that acts_as_list gives the newly added item a position number which makes it show up 1st rather than last? I don't want to flip the positions of the other items though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New entries in a list are [by default](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/f625892b8d2854c9d72f5398f3ea6d9c2e317e06/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb#L35) added to the bottom. You can specify the `add_new_at` option to have new entries added at the top:

```
acts_as_list scope: :object, add_new_at: :top
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: With that I get `undefined method 'todo_id' for #<Image:0xa357e30>`

Comment: Sure I added it to the question